# Get time range in a formatted time list using current time

Tags: android, time, time-format

I have a formatted time list like following:

00:30:00 -
01:00:00 -
. 
.
.
.
23:30:00

How can I get the range between currentTime-(1 hour) and currentTime+(3 hours) from that list in Android?

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GTC"));
                    long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                    Log.i("time", ""+now);


                    timeTableAdapter = new TimeTableAdapter(
                            TimeTableAdvanced.this, R.layout.timetable_item,
                            timeTableList);

                    adapterCount = timeTableAdapter.getCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {

                        String inputString = timeTableList.get(i)
                                .getDepartureTime();

                        Date dat;
                        try {
                            dat = df.parse(inputString);

                            if (dat.getTime() <= now+(3*3600000) && dat.getTime() >= now-3600000 ) {
                                View item = timeTableAdapter.getView(i, null,
                                        null);
                                timetablelayout.addView(item);

                                View line = new View(TimeTableAdvanced.this);
                                line.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
                                line.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                                        .getColor(R.color.black));
                                timetablelayout.addView(line);
                            }
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: In what format is that time list stored? text file? string? List object? What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: String formatted.  I tried to change string formatted times and current time to miliseconds and then tried to add the ones in the range by checking if the difference is -1 or 3 hours but nothing is added.

Comment: Can you post the code/solution of what you have tried so far? That should give you better feedback

Comment: Yes, I edited my code. Can you check it out no0w, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difficulties here.

Suppose you have X = current time in millis

```
HOUR_IN_MILLIS = 3600000
Time A = X - 1 hrs = X - HOUR_IN_MILLIS millis
Time B = X + 3 hrs = X + (3 * HOUR_IN_MILLIS) millis
```

If you need a range in 1/2 hour intervals, you iterate

```
for (long i = A; i <= B; i =+ HOUR_IN_MILLIS/2) { //add time to list }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Apparently, I was not only getting time but also date while taking miliseconds for current time. Here is the solution:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                Date now;
                long nowtime = 0;
                try {
                    now = df.parse(date);
                    nowtime=now.getTime();
                    Log.i("time", ""+now);
                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }



                timeTableAdapter = new TimeTableAdapter(
                        TimeTableAdvanced.this, R.layout.timetable_item,
                        timeTableList);

                adapterCount = timeTableAdapter.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < adapterCount; i++) {

                    String inputString = timeTableList.get(i)
                            .getDepartureTime();

                    Date dat;
                    try {
                        dat = df.parse(inputString);
                        Log.i("time1", ""+dat.getTime());
                        Log.i("time2", ""+nowtime);
                        if (dat.getTime() <= nowtime+(3*3600000) && dat.getTime() >= nowtime-3600000 ) {
                            View item = timeTableAdapter.getView(i, null,
                                    null);
                            timetablelayout.addView(item);

                            View line = new View(TimeTableAdvanced.this);
                            line.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
                            line.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                                    .getColor(R.color.black));
                            timetablelayout.addView(line);
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
```